# Optimal way to use function for property in AutoMapper ProjectTo IQueryable tree

Tags: sql, entity-framework, automapper, projection

I'm using AutoMapper `.ProjectTo<OrderDto>()` to map some `Order` to `OrderDto`.

The original Order is a pretty big object with around 30 properties and 15 collections.

For my OrderDto I have a property `DisplayStatus` with some custom logic based on 4 properties in the original Order. I don't need those properties in my final OrderDto, I just need them to do something like `GetDisplayStatus()`.

I have tried several ways of doing this and none of them feels satisfying to me so my guess is I must be doing something wrong. There has to be a better way.

FIrst thing I tried was to use a *custom value resolver* but you can't use them inside an IQueryable projection because they can't be translated to Linq (if I understood correctly).

Then I tried doing something like this

```
.ForMember(target => target.DisplayStatus, option => option.MapFrom(source => GetDisplayStatus(source))
```

The problem with this is that Entity Framework consider this to be a "blackbox" and have no way to know what I need and what I don't. Therefore the whole source object is passed to the function. The consequence is that the final SQL Query applies a `Select` on all the columns from `Order`, bloating the query with a big chunk of unnecessary data and performance goes down by a big margin.

In the end the current way of doing this in our codebase is something like this

```
.ForMember(target => target.DisplayStatus, option => option.MapFrom(source => 
 GetDisplayStatus(new TempOrder{
     someProperty = source.someProperty
     anotherPropery = source.anotherProperty
}))
```

By doing this I'm able to narrow down exactly what properties of the original Order I want to pass to my `GetDisplayStatus()` function and the final SQL Query stay clean.

Downside to this is that the code can quickly become pretty ugly when the things you want to pass to your function require a bit a work themselves.

```
.ForMember(target => target.DisplayStatus, option => option.MapFrom(source => 
 GetDisplayStatus(source.OrderProducts.Where(//a lot of work here too//).Select(op => 
 new TempOrderProduct
 {
     ProductTypeId = op.ProductTypeId,
     HasFiles = op.OrderFiles.Any(),
     VisitDate = op.VisitDate
 }), source.OrderStatus)))
```

Again, this does not feel right. Is there a better way to do this ?

Thank you.

**Edit**

Here is the same query without AutoMapper as requested in the comments

```
public static IQueryable<OrderDTO> MapOrderDTO(this IQueryable<Orders> orders)
        {
            return orders
                .Select(order => new OrderDTO
                {
                    OrderID = order.OrderId,
                    OrderCreationDate = order.OrderCreationDate,
                    OrderStatus = order.OrderStatus,
                    DisplayStatus = GetDisplayStatus(order.OrderProducts
                                   .Where(//a lot of work//)
                                   .Select(op => new TempOrderProduct 
                                   { ProductTypeId = op.ProductTypeId,
                                     HasFiles = op.OrderFiles.Any(),
                                     VisitDate = op.VisitDate }),
                                     order.OrderStatus)
                                   })
                });
        }
```

Comment: First try to write it as an EF LINQ query, without AM. Then we'll see how we can add AM back.

Comment: I already did that, then I posted the issue on the EF Core Github repository and their answer was to use AutoMapper. 

It's basically the same thing but instead of ProjectTo<>() I have an extension method on IQueryable<Order> and in that extension method I do the exact same logic for my GetDisplayStatut() function.

Comment: Post the EF linq query that achieves what you want. If that's not possible, then you should use `Map` instead.

Comment: Done. But this is **not** what I want, it's the exact same workaround but in EF linq fashion.

Comment: That can only work with client evaluation. You can always fetch what you need and then call `Map`.